# Is it possible to have IF formula delete a row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that right now pulls and outputs on another sheet whether the B1 Cell is equal to “YES” then print A1 in the new sheets Cell I have the formula entered in, if it is not then it leaves the cell blank and this goes on for as many cells as needed.

Here is my formula

```
=IF((Sheet1!B1)=“YES”,Sheet!1A1,””)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to change the formula to where if it is not equal to “YES” then instead of leaving the Cell blank it deletes the entire row instead.

I know the final ,””) part of the formula is what I used to state the Cell will be blank. I’m just unaware if there is a function or anything I can input instead to state if not “YES” then delete the Row.

Example of what is happening:

If I have these entries in Sheet 1

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85 | YES |
| 2 | 47 | NO |
| 3 | 74 | YES |

The output on Sheet 2 using my formula will be:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85 |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 74 |  |

I am looking for it to look like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85 |  |
| 2 | 74 |  |
| 3 |  |  |

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `FILTER()` function. Many post on SO that cover this feature.

Comment: @JvdV thanks for the advice, I am going to look into this and see if I can solve it using this.

Comment: If you do need to delete the row, you'll have to use VBA.

Comment: @jsheeran I don’t know that it needs to be deleted. I just don’t want spaces between the outputs.

Comment: Use FILTER() when you have Office365 or AGGREGATE()/SMALL if you have an older Excel version